# Connect to Linux-based VPN Using Windows 7's Native VPN Connection Wizard?

Tags: linux, windows-7, vpn, ubuntu

Does anyone know if I can run a Linux-based VPN server on my Ubuntu server and connect to it using Windows 7’s native VPN connection wizard? If this is possible, which VPN server should I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure on what Windows 7 is looking for but previous versions of Windows natively supported PPTP.  The Linux server for this is called PoPToP.

http://www.poptop.org/

I too however do prefer OpenVPN but if your requirements are that it works with Windows natively PoPToP is what you're looking for.  We use it where I work for two reasons.  It's what they were using when I started here and it works with the iPhone where OpenVPN doesn't currently.

Comment: Looks like Windows 7 may include some sort of IPSEC client as well.  http://wiki.strongswan.org/wiki/strongswan/Windows7

Comment: Link appears dead.

Answer (score 5):

Linux's IPSec servers (FreeSWAN, OpenSWAN, StrongSWAN) all support L2TP, which WinXP, Vista (and i presume 7) all support natively. Installing the certificate is a minor PITA, but after that it works like PPTP, only without the nasty vulnerabilities in the latter!

Comment: Please put in a reference to the "nasty vulnerabilities" for those of us not familiar with PPTP.

Comment: Sure - https://www.schneier.com/academic/pptp/

Answer (score 5):

Got it working! Thanks 3dinfluence!

Ubuntu Server:

1. apt-get install pptpd
2. Edit /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf and uncomment: net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
3. Reboot
4. Forward all necessary VPN ports to the Ubuntu server and make sure there is no firewall blocking them

Windows 7:

1. Create a new connection to a VPN
2. Follow the wizard and enter the external address of the Ubuntu server

Good times.

Comment: Would be nice if you mention what are all the ports to forward

Comment: Also a recommended disclosure about pptpd: https://jasonschaefer.com/pptp-server-on-the-openwrt/

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to use OpenVPN instead.

[This page](http://www.fiberworks.com/DNN/Support/OpenVPN/tabid/171/language/en-US/Default.aspx) has instructions for downloading the OpenVPN GUI client for use on Windows 7; I am using it now.